# Alternate Out of Order TCP Packets problem

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, tcp

I have a Windows network with embedded nodes connected to a series of Cisco switches. I have been seeing some serious network problems starting a few days ago.

I used Wireshark to capture the network trace and see every alternate TCP packets being marked as "out of order".

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Like this?](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200803/msg00317.html)

Are you using a spanning port on your Cisco switch? It might be possible that you are seeing duplicate packets. Can you verify that they are not duplicates?

Also, if you have access to a hub try using that inline on your segment (rather than the spanning port). If you don't see "Out of Order" packets something is wrong with how you set up your spanning port.

Answer (score 1):

The other common cause of out of order packets is load-balancing links.  Do you have multiple networks/vlans?